# Is the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack open source? Are there FOSS alternatives?

Tags: open-source, virtual-machine, virtual-box

I was wondering whether [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) is open source. Unlike VirtualBox itself it looks like it isn't.

It adds support for USB 2.0, for RDP and disk encryption.

Are there any alternatives to allow for forwarding USB HID traffic in VirtualBox (like a user-made extension-pack) or is there a good FOSS alternative to VirtualBox+Extension Pack altogether?

---

So to be more precise: I'm looking for recommendations

- on open source software that allows me to have functionalities of the Extension Pack in VirtualBox. For example FOSS forks of VirtualBox, or open source Extension Packs for the standard VirtualBox.
- on FOSS hypervisors (including potential extensions to them) that are similar to VirtualBox.
  It should run on Debian, host arbitrary OSes, have a GUI, allow for bridging (Internet-access) and NAT (for private networks of VMs) and offer good performance.

---

**Edit**: The answer is **[AQemu](https://github.com/tobimensch/aqemu) + qemu-kvm**. Now I haven't tried Xen and some other GUIs like virt-manager, Archipel and Kimchi.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Also, this site is not about clarifying license issues, or answering "does software X do Z"; it is about "what software meets [explicit requirements here]".

Comment: Okay. I clarified what I'm looking for. I hope it's clear enough now. For clarifying license issues: I was wondering whether I should rather post this on opensource.stackexchange but I researched further and despite some false blogposts about it, it really looks like it's closed source. I could not find the source code of it. I'm just not 100% sure because e.g. there might be an easy way to inspect the code even though that's not what most people would call "open source".

Comment: No, it's not. Oracle's license page is here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ

Comment: You still assume everyone knows exactly what VirtualBox and more precisely the Extension Pack are doing, in detail. It's still not clear what features you need. E.g. do you just want to box a single OS (which) on the same host OS? Or must it support multiple host OSes and be available cross-platform? Must it support headless mode – or rather have good mouse support? Is seamless mode important? Disk types, network stuff (like bridging or NATting)? "Most functionalities of X" is a bit broad and unclear at the same time.